# nomencl.ist not found

Tags: mactex, mac, paths, nomenclature

I'm on `osx` [MacTex] and I'm trying to use `nomencl` package. The problem is that:

```
makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls
```

does not work, printing

```
 index file nomencl.ist not found
```

Lookig for the files (`find / -name "nomencl*"`) returns the path:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist
```

and doing:

```
makeindex thesis.nlo -s /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls
```

works correctly.

It seems a problem of path. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is what I have done:

1. Updated to MacTex2015
2. Run TexLive manager from the `/Applications/TeXLive Utility` and updated all
3. Go back to TexShop or other utility, and manually update the engine to 2015 (on mine, El Capitan, it originally showed 2013, even after updating MacTex2015 -- this link https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf does not contain the correct information): from `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/universal-darwin` to `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin`.

4) Quit TexShop and start it again. Now the menu will show 'Nomenclature' and 'Makeindex' as macros. Run these as usual to typeset it.

Note: `% arara` directives do not seem to work with this distribution, so one has to run Nomenclature and Makeindex separately. Additions to how to make array work with this distribution and TexShop gladly received.